# How to maximize or minimize $2y^2 + x^2$ subject to the constraint $x+y=1$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

How do I maximize or minimize $2y^2 + x^2$ such that $x + y = 1$?

I'm a newbie and don't know how to start.

Comment: It will help to describe to people what math you already know. Do you know Calculus? Lagrange Multipliers? Quadratic Forms? There are many ways to solve these problems, so any indication how you would like/understand the solution will be helpful.

Comment: I know calculus

Comment: Also note that with whatever answer you get, don't expect to find a global maximum.

Answer (score 1):

**Elementary method**

By $y=1-x$,
$$2y^2+x^2=2(1-x)^2+x^2=3x^2-4x+2=3(x-\frac23)^2+\frac23$$

which has the minimum value of $\displaystyle\frac23$ at $\displaystyle x=\frac23$.

Comment: $2/3$, $x=2/3$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: let $$f(x,y)=2y^2+x^2$$ under the condition $$x+y=1$$ with $$y=1-x$$ you will have $$f(x,1-x)=2(1-x)^2+x^2$$ and this reduces the Problem in one variable.

Comment: How do I show that it's a minimum or a maximum point

Comment: I'm grateful for your response.

Comment: you must compute the derivative with respect to $x$

Answer (score 0):

1 - Reduce the complexity of your problem by letting $y=1-x$ and substitute that into your equation.

2 - Take the derivative of the simplified express and set that equal to zero.  Solve for the roots to find the turning points

3 - In general, if you can't graph the equation, take the second derivative to analyse the gradient of the equation from point 2.  By finding the second derivative and inserting  values which correspond to *just before* and *just after* your turning points, you can deduce whether the point is a minima or a maxima.

Answer (score 0):

By C-S
$$x^2+2y^2=\frac{(2+1)(x^2+2y^2)}{3}\geq\frac{(\sqrt2x+\sqrt2y)^2}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$$
The equality occurs for $(\sqrt2,1)||(x,\sqrt2y)$, which says that $\frac{2}{3}$ is a minimal value.

The maximum does not exist, of course.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Solution $[1]$
$2y^2+x^2=t⇔\dfrac {y^2}{t/2}+\dfrac{x^2}t=1$

Since this is ellipse, when this is tangent to $x+y=1$, it's minimum. There is no maximum.

$2(1-x)^2+x^2-t=0$

$⇔3x^2-4x+2-t=0$

$D/4=4-3(2-t)=0⇔t=2/3$

Solution $[2]$

$x=\cos^2a,y=\sin^2a$

$t=2y^2+x^2=2\sin^4a+\cos^4a=2\sin^4a+(1-\sin^2a)^2$

$=3\sin^4a-2\sin^2a+1=3(\sin^2a-1/3)^2+2/3\geq\frac23$//

Answer (score 0):

A bit Geometry:

1) $y + x = 1$.

A straight line with $y-intercept $ $1$, $x- intercept$  $1$, 
$m = -1$.

2) Consider  $2y^2 + x^2 = c^2$, with $c>0$.

Problem: maximize or minimize $c^2$ , given condition 1).

Rewriting :

$\frac{y^2}{(c^2/2)} + \frac{x^2}{c^2} = 1$.

This is an ellipse centered at the origin, with

minor axis $c/√2$ along the $y-axis$, and

major axis $c$ along the $x - axis$.

Smaller $c$ shrinks the ellipse, larger $c$ blows it up.

3 possibilities:

1) The ellipse intersects

$ y + x = 1$ in 2  distinct points.

2) The ellipse touches the given line.

3) The ellipse and line have no point in common.

We are interested in case 2), minimal $c^2$.

2)The tangent to the ellipse has the slope $m = -1$.

Differentiating $2y^2 + x^2 = c^2$ with respect to $x$:

$4y(dy/dx) + 2x = 0$.

$dy/dx = \frac{-x}{2y} = - 1$, or $2y = x$.

Combining with $y + x = 1$ yields

$y = 1/3$, $x = 2/3$.

$min$:

$c^2 = 2y^2 + x^2 $= $2(1/9)+4/9$= $2/3$.